# Export Azure users with identity ExternalAzureAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Exporting a csv file to get a list of users in Azure.  User is a guest user but with the Identities marked as ExternalAzureAd.  I can get guest users but it does not export the ones with Identities marked as ExternalAzureAD, only ones in with Identities in XX.onmicrosoft.com, where XX is my domain name.

Here is the powershell command that I'm running:

`Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true"  | select DisplayName, Mail | Export-Csv guests.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have below **guest users** in my Azure AD tenant with `Identities` like this:

[image]

To export Azure AD **guest users** with identity `ExternalAzureAD` only, you can make use of below MS Graph PowerShell script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"
Get-MgUser -Filter "userType eq 'Guest'" -Property "displayName,mail,Identities" | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $guestuser = $_ 
    $guestuser.Identities | Where-Object { $_.Issuer -eq "ExternalAzureAD" } | 
    Select-Object @{Name="DisplayName"; Expression={$guestuser.DisplayName}}, 
                  @{Name="Mail"; Expression={$guestuser.Mail}}, 
                  Issuer, 
                  SignInType
} | Export-Csv -Path "guests.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the exported file, I got **guest users** with identity `ExternalAzureAD` successfully in list like below:

[image]